# Cannot enable migrations for Entity Framework in class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I just got on board with EF 5 and am using their code-first migrations tool but I seem to get an error when I try to enable migrations.

I type `Enable-Migrations` into the package manager console and then it says

> No classes deriving from DbContext found in the current project.
>   Edit the generated Configuration class to specify the context to enable migrations for.
>   Code First Migrations enabled for project MyApp.MvcUI.

It then creates a Migrations folder and a Configuration class in my MvcUI project. Thing is, my DbContext lives in a class library project called MyApp.Domain. It should be doing all that in that project and should have no problem finding my DbContext.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Oh wow, nevermind. I'm dumb.

In the Nuget package manager console there is a dropdown menu at the top labeled "Default Project:". Make sure you set that to the project you want to run the command against.

Hopefully this helps someone else avoid my embarrassing mistake.

Comment: Had no idea this was there.  You rock.

Comment: Can not believe I missed that dropdown thanks a lot.

Comment: @JaredStroeb glad I could help. Don't worry, I couldn't believe I missed it either.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Missed it too.

Answer (score 11):

There are actually 3 ways to make Nuget commands run in a specific project:

1. [Package Manager Console] Set the active project in the dropdown at the top of the console toolwindow
2. [Package Manager Console] Look for a parameter to specify the project.  For some cmdlets I've seen -ProjectName and some use -Project
3. [Solution Explorer] Right-click the project you want, and use the graphical package manager window (Manage NuGet Packages...).

Comment: I'm guessing all the third option does is set the package manager console drop down for you right?