# Ef Migration Code Based

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm starting to turn migration manuals in my solution.
But I have a problem, it is several days that I could not understand.

My solution is divided into several projects, a project for the view (Sedna.UI) a project for the db where are my entity and my contexts. (Sedna.Domain).

I have 3 contexts, 2 have automatic migrations while the main one I would turn migration manual (SednaContext)

Nuget package manager console there is a dropdown and I select the Default project "Sedna.Domain" then when i run Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Sedna.Domain.UnitOfWork.SednaContext ... I get an error: "No migrations configuration type 'Sedna .Domain.Migrations.Configuration 'was found in the assembly "Sedna.Domain" "while I find him in the project.

I'm going crazy I do not understand why?

[Screencast](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=64110E34E82E4DC3%211778)

Comment: I found the problem was because my project was compiled x86 , I put any cpu and I do not understand why it works

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the ContextProjectName as well. http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2014/05/entity-framework-migrations-no-context.html Also see [Enable Migrations with Context in Separate Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126711/enable-migrations-with-context-in-separate-assembly)