# How to migrate PostgreSQL in MVC using query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql

Basically these lines are used for Data Migration in SQL Server But i want to Migrate in PostgreSQL.
So please help me. Thank You.

```cs
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 Enable-Migrations -ProjectName MyContextProjectNameHere -StartUpProjectName MyStartUpProjectNameHere -Verbose
```

Comment: Nice one! A reference would be nice in such cases; So that other users can get some help is case of slight different scenarios.

Comment: Thanx you can find the similar solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126711/enable-migrations-with-context-in-separate-assembly please do check this might help you